# Consume C# Webservice with Delphi using Attributes

Tags: c#, web-services, delphi

I try to consume a `C#`-Webservice with a `Delphi`-Client. Now when i try to send a request, I found out, that the Webservice needs attributes on specific nodes I don't have in the wsdl-classes.

What it Looks like:

```
<Value>008</Value>
```

What it has to look like:

```
<Value xmlns:d6p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d6p1:string">008</Value>
```

Additionally, the value of `i:type` has to be set according to the `Value`-Node.

How can I modify my Delphi service class to add those attributes without parsing the Datastring of the Requeststream?

Answer (score 0):

u must to override objecttosoap of the class adding the attribute to the child node:

```
result := inherited;
valuenode := result.childnodes.findnode('value');
if valuenode<>nil then
  valuenode.attributes['i:type' := 'd6p1:string';
```